# Cannot fetch a value with awk inside a block

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to fetch the value of `Layout` with `gawk` inside blocks containing `/virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/` that look like this :

```bash
# omreport storage vdisk controller=0 vdisk=16
Virtual Disk 16 on Controller PERC H730 Mini (Embedded)

Controller PERC H730 Mini (Embedded)
ID                                : 16
Status                            : Ok
Name                              : Virtual Disk 16
State                             : Ready
Hot Spare Policy violated         : Not Applicable
Encrypted                         : No
Layout                            : RAID-0
Size                              : 3,725.50 GB (4000225165312 bytes)
T10 Protection Information Status : No
Associated Fluid Cache State      : Not Applicable
Device Name                       : /dev/sdp
Bus Protocol                      : SAS
Media                             : HDD
Read Policy                       : Read Ahead
Write Policy                      : Force Write Back
Cache Policy                      : Not Applicable
Stripe Element Size               : 64 KB
Disk Cache Policy                 : Disabled

#
```

I type the following `gawk` command to the Layout of the last Virtual Disk :

```bash
# omreport storage vdisk controller=0 | gawk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/{inBlock=1}! /virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/{inBlock=0}inBlock == 1 && /Layout/{value=$NF}END{print value}'
#
```

I expect to see for the example above :

```bash
RAID-0
```

The `/Layout/` regexp is always inside the `omreport storage vdisk controller=0` blocks and `omreport` returns one or blocks.

In the case of multiple blocks, I need the `Layout` value of the last `Virtual Disk` name matching `/virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/`.

EDIT0 : Here is a block containing a `Virtual Disk` name NOT matching `/virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/` :

```bash
# omreport storage vdisk controller=0 vdisk=0
Virtual Disk 0 on Controller PERC H730 Mini (Embedded)

Controller PERC H730 Mini (Embedded)
ID                                : 0
Status                            : Ok
Name                              : SYSTEM
State                             : Ready
Hot Spare Policy violated         : Not Assigned
Encrypted                         : No
Layout                            : RAID-1
Size                              : 465.25 GB (499558383616 bytes)
T10 Protection Information Status : No
Associated Fluid Cache State      : Not Applicable
Device Name                       : /dev/sda
Bus Protocol                      : SATA
Media                             : HDD
Read Policy                       : Read Ahead
Write Policy                      : Write Back
Cache Policy                      : Not Applicable
Stripe Element Size               : 64 KB
Disk Cache Policy                 : Disabled

#
```

Comment: @anubhava You're right. Just added the expected output.

Comment: could you update the question with some details on what constitutes a 'block' of ouput; of particular interest would be a sample set of input that shows a couple blocks (one that matches the search requirement, one that does not match the search requirement); or will your `omreport` call always generate just the single 'block'?

Comment: Your awk command is using some gawk extensions - are you using GNU awk? Please [edit] your question to show the output of `awk --version`.

Comment: @markp-fuso I added some clarification

Comment: @EdMorton I'm using GNU Awk.

Comment: As I requested for your previous question and you said you would do for the next one - please post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that we can simply copy/paste to test with so we can help you. Posting multiple separate "blocks" doesn't show us what separates the blocks and generally isn't nearly as useful as 1 input file containing multiple blocks and the expected output given that input.

Comment: @EdMorton I'd love to post the whole file but pastebin.com is filtered by our PaloAlto firewall. Do you know other well known text storage site ?

Comment: That's not how you use this site. You don't just post whatever large piece of code or input files you have lying around that has the problem buried somewhere inside it and you definitely never post anything on some other site and then link to it. Instead you create a [mcve] that demonstrates your needs and post that in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `gnu awk` solution:

```bash
omreport storage vdisk controller=0 |
awk -F '\\s*:\\s**' '
BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}
/virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/ {inBlock=1}
inBlock && $1 == "Layout" {print $2; exit}
'

RAID-0
```

If you don't have `gnu awk` then `IGNORECASE` flag won't work and you should use this solution:

```bash
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*' '
/Virtual[[:blank:]]*Disk[[:blank:]]*[0-9]+/ {inBlock=1}
inBlock && $1 ~ /Layout/ {print $2; exit}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Using regex in GNU `awk` with your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS= '
match($0,/: Virtual Disk [0-9]+\n.*Layout[^:]+:[[:space:]]+([^\n]+)/,arr){
  print arr[1]
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Love it :) ! If there are more than two matching blocks, how do you print the latest matching block ? : `print arr[length(arr)]` ?

Comment: @SebMa, this assumes that you have only 1 entry in file. Can you have more than 1 entry if yes then please do let me know I can improve it, cheers.

Comment: By entry, you mean block right ?

Comment: @SebMa, yes I mean from `Virtual Disk` to `Layout` thing, does it come only once OR more than once in your file? This code considers that its coming on 1 time but if its coming more than that I can add 1 more solution on same then, cheers.

Comment: More than once.

Comment: @SebMa, are your blocks are having null/empty lines in between 2 occurrences? eg: from `#` to till `Disk Cache Policy #` and null lines then again these? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: In my case, empty line always follow a `Disk Cache Policy : \w+` line. This is true for all the blocks/entries.

Comment: @SebMa, if blank lines are there after last # of yours(shown in samples) and then again you have complete block pf same kind of data then this code should work IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- all blocks have 2 lines that start with `Name` and `Layout`
- the `Name` line always appears before the `Layout` line
- looking for a 'block' of output where the `Name` field matches the regex  `/virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/`
- when we find a match make note of the associated `Layout` value
- if there are multiple matches only print the value of the last `Layout`

To simulate the `omreport` output in my environment:

```
$ cat disk.out
# omreport storage vdisk controller=0 vdisk=16
Virtual Disk 16 on Controller PERC H730 Mini (Embedded)

Controller PERC H730 Mini (Embedded)
ID                                : 16
Status                            : Ok
Name                              : Virtual Disk 16
...
Layout                            : RAID-0
Size                              : 3,725.50 GB (4000225165312 bytes)
...

# omreport storage vdisk controller=0 vdisk=0
Virtual Disk 0 on Controller PERC H730 Mini (Embedded)

Controller PERC H730 Mini (Embedded)
ID                                : 0
Status                            : Ok
Name                              : SYSTEM
...
Layout                            : RAID-1
Size                              : 465.25 GB (499558383616 bytes)
...
```

**NOTE:** `disk.out` contains the full text of OP's sample blocks; output of the `cat` has been edited here for brevity

One `awk` idea:

```
cat disk.out | 
gawk '
BEGIN                   { IGNORECASE=1 }
$1=="Name"              { if ($0 ~ /virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/)
                             inBlock = 1
                          else
                             inBlock = 0
                        }
inBlock && $1=="Layout" { layout = $3 }
END                     { if (layout) print layout }
'
```

**NOTE:** `IGNORECASE` requires `GNU awk`

This generates:

```
RAID-0
```

Comment: You're right, I just added another block, please take a look at my EDIT0.

Comment: @SebMa your latest update includes another block that *does* match your regex of `/virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/`

Comment: Maybe I was a little ambiguous. All blocks contain `/Layout/` pattern : some blocks contain`Name` matching `/virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/` and some blocks contain`Name` NOT matching `/virtual\s*disk\s*[0-9]+/`.